# Create stored procedure with specific schema in MYSQL and grant execute permission to user

Tags: mysql

Hello i have two db schemas "**results**" and "**base**". I am trying to create stored procedure in "results" database, and at the same time to give permission to user to run this procedure. What i did is:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS results.truncateResultsTable //
CREATE PROCEDURE results.truncateResultsTable(genId VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SET @genId = genId;
    SET @q = CONCAT('TRUNCATE TABLE results_' , @genId);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION results.truncateResultsTable TO 'lam_api'@'%';
END //
```

But getting this error

```
execute command denied to user 'lam_api'@'%' for routine 'results.truncateResultsTable
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is right solution, i had couple of issues. **GARANT** part was misplaced, also was missing **DELIMITER** ;

```
 DELIMITER //
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS results.truncateResultsTable //
    CREATE PROCEDURE results.truncateResultsTable(genId VARCHAR(255))
    BEGIN
        SET @genId = genId;
        SET @q = CONCAT('TRUNCATE TABLE results_' , @genId);
        PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END //
    DELIMITER ;
    
    GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE results.truncateResultsTable TO 'lam_api'@'%';
```